# When are the powers of 2 sum-free mod n?

Tags: nt.number-theory, additive-combinatorics

I've encountered the following question in my research:

Let $A$ be a subset of
$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Let me call $A$ "sum-free" if there is no solution to
$x+y=z$ for $x,y,z \in A$ with **distinct** $x$ and $y$.
The addition is of course mod $n$.

**Question:** For which $n$ is the set $A = \{2^x \!\!\mod n: x>0\}$ (the set of powers of $2$)
sum-free? I'm assuming that $n$ is odd.

Does anyone have an idea how to approach this question?

Comment: For most $n$ it's probably not, or at least for most prime $n$, because on average powers of $2$ are at least conjecturally a positive proportion of numbers mod $p$.

Comment: What are the values of $n$ smaller than, say, $100$, with the property in question? What does OEIS say?

Comment: @Seva If my program is correct, the first few odd $n$ with the property are 1, 3, 7, 15, 21, 31, 51, 63, 73, 85, 89, 91, 93, 105, 117, 127, 133, 151, 195.  This sequence is not in the OEIS.

Comment: I find $379$ such numbers $\leq 10000$.

Comment: A numerical test up to $2 \cdot 10^6$ seems to say that the order of 2 for such n is around $\sqrt{n}$, so Jeremy's heuristic is right.

Comment: To add on my original question, I'm mostly interested in the existence of such n for which the order of 2 is "large" (namely something like n/poly-log(n) ).

Thank you all for helpful comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is very similar to the one [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172706/primes-dividing-2a2b-1/172714), and the heuristic should apply equally well. In particular, $A$ is sum-free if and only if there does not exist a $k$ with $k \ne \frac{n+1}{2}$ so that $k$ and $1-k$ are both in $A$, and the chances of this occurring are approximately $e^{-r^{2}/\phi(n)}$, where $r = |A|$. Hence, one should only expect $A$ to be sum-free if $|A| \approx \sqrt{\phi(n)}$. This is a very infrequent situation, but it is certainly not impossible. (In particular, it is easy to see that if $n = 2^{k} - 1$, then $A$ is sum-free. Also, one could look for divisors $n$ of $2^{k} - 1$ with $n \gg k^{2}$ to find other examples where $A$ is sum-free.)